# how to use of speed and time to calculate next time's latitude and longitude

Tags: java, gps

I am trying to get latitude and longitude based on speed and start basic points.am trying with this JAVA code.

my aim is  basic start latitude,longitude point-A with 0 speed,next finding location point-B i.e. after 30 seconds with 32 speed next location point is 18.473993,79.14167, then point c..etc..

Here is my code :

```
      public class DemoCallLatLng {
        public static void main(String s[]){        
        double speed = 32.5;//random speed
        double time = 0.5;//30seconds
        double lat1 = 18.4742516;//start latitude point
        double lon1 = 79.14007;//start longitude point
        double distance = speed * time;//distance calculation
        double lon2;
        double lat2;
        lat2 =asin(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos('K')+Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin('K')*Math.cos('K'))
        double dlon=atan2(Math.sin(tc)*Math.sin('K')*Math.cos(lat1),Math.cos('K')-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2))
        lon2=mod( lon1-dlon +Math.PI,2*Math.PI )-Math.PI;
        System.out.println(lat2+" : "+dlon+" : "+lon2);
    }
}
```

Comment: so  What is the problem?

Comment: am not get output. is anything wrong in code.

Comment: You copied the code from the wrong answer, in the link you posted below. Unfortunatley it is the accepted answer. Look there at the other two answers , they are much better and cleaner coded. While the first is only terribly bad explained pseudo code

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the direction in which you are going, you can not find new position only by knowing distance and speed. (speed is a scalar quantity).

You will need to have velocity in stead (separate x and y components).

If you know direction somehow (direction angle θ maybe), you can even break the speed into x and y components.

> velocityX = speed * cos(θ)
>
> velocityY = speed * sin(θ)

---

When you know both components of velocity, you can use following.

> newPositionX = oldPositionX + velocityX * time

and

> newPositionY = oldPositionY + velocityY * time

The velocity components should have appropriate units (scaled to work with lat-long)

---

Just make sure θ is angle between direction that you are heading to and north direction

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your code and all other answer make the same basic error.

sin() and cos() need an angle in radians, not degrees.

So convert that latitude and longitude to radians before using

```
double latRad = Math.toRadians(latitude);
```

And there are much other things wrong:

- speed is measured in meters per seconds. so always use this unit in formulas, convert before if input is in miles or km/h.
- time: the unit of time is 1 second , not one minute: correct that in your code.
- if your variable are not in SI units (Internationaly normed system of units: meter, second etc.) then you should name them containing the name of the unit: e.g speedKmh, or numMinutes
- To calculate a position from a given one, you need a direction, measured in degrees (0 - 360). so this is addionally input. In your code this is the variable tc: tc is meant to be the direction. It could be derived from the word "true course". This probably should be in radians, too. But probably is an mathematical angle (east = 0, counterclockwise) while geographic angle is north = 0°, clockwise raising.
- What the hell you want to achieve with sin('K') ???. You should remember from school that sin() takes an angle as argument, not a letter.
  -

finally you should find a better source for that code, the sorce where you took the code from, has two other answers which are far better and ready to use. Look there and throw away the current method.

Comment: thanks @AlexWien, please can you help me with some code. and how to avoid sea,oceans,forests latlngs ..etc, how to get only valid road path of latlngs.

Comment: @Hydrogen To avoid sea, oceans, etc: This seems to be above your technial range. If you have such problems with a relative simple code, then you need some years more of experience: you need th evector data of street polygons which  are availabe for free by OpenStreetMap or paid by TomTom and Nokia.

Answer (score 0):

your code had several syntax errors

below is the correct code,
only 1 issue remains, what is `tc`, i used constant = `11` just to run the code

```
public class DemoCallLatLng {
    public static void main(String s[]){        
    double speed = 32.5;//random speed
    double time = 0.5;//30seconds
    double lat1 = 18.4742516;//start latitude point
    double lon1 = 79.14007;//start longitude point
    double distance = speed * time;//distance calculation
    double lon2;
    double lat2;

        lat2 =Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos('K')+Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin('K')*Math.cos('K'));
        double dlon=Math.atan2(Math.sin(11)*Math.sin('K')*Math.cos(lat1),Math.cos('K')-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
        lon2=( lon1-dlon +Math.PI % 2*Math.PI )-Math.PI;
        System.out.println(lat2+" : "+dlon+" : "+lon2);
    }
}
```

**your errors were:**

1- asin ==> Math.asin()

2- atan2 ==> Math.atan2 ()

3- there is no such method `mod()`, if u mean modulus, in java it's `%`
so `mod( lon1-dlon +Math.PI,2*Math.PI )` ==> `lon1-dlon +Math.PI % 2*Math.PI`

i am not sure if i missed other syntax errors, but mainly they were missing `Math.`
the mod() function, and finally as i told you the `tc` variable at line

```
double dlon=atan2(Math.sin(tc)*...
```

this code now generate output, but i think it's not correct due to using `11` instead of `tc`

**Output:**

```
-0.7347912647318792 : 0.4902491126709713 : 79.094647327649
```

Comment: thanks @Yazan, am got this code from **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352921/how-to-use-direction-angle-and-speed-to-calculate-next-times-latitude-and-longi**,

Comment: @acecloudsmaps it looks like a pesuedo code more than a running code, if u figure out what is `tc`, u can make use of it. maybe :)

Comment: tc is an angle in radians, and should not  hav ethe value of 11 (0 - 2*Pi), why the hell you take the sin() of 'K'. This all makes no sense. The code will never run that appoorach.

Comment: @AlexWien i used `11` as constant randomly picked just to make this code run, that was mentioned in my answer. other 'K' ... was used by OP.

Comment: It makes no sense to make a code compile clean, which never will produce any sensefull output. First is to understand, then code.

Comment: @AlexWien IMO in order to make the OP understand the code he should have a clean code first, then he can start working on getting what he needs. syntax and compile errors will not help him understand what is the logical error...

Comment: A totally wrong code, whether or not compile clean does not help anything. He took the wrong source of information, and made evrything worse. This is lost time, and not helpfull at all. The place where he took the formula from, has two answers with well written clean code, working rigt out of the box. Totally not understandable why he took the wrong answer. maybe beacuse it was the accepted one.

Comment: @AlexWien may be, i think what made it more complex for this question is the proposed code had syntax and compile errors, this is 1 side, and the other was the result (in case the code was compile clean) is not true, what i did is fixing the compile part, without looking at the logical process of the code. actually this question is really messed up :)